# Core Data making a complex query

Tags: ios, core-data

In my app i'm using core data as a db manager. This is more or less my database scheme:

```
Table: Device(
id: String,
name: String,
specsId: String
);
Table: Specs(
specsId: String,
/**/
);
```

The two tables are not joined in any way.

What i want to do is when i query a device from the Device table then automatically query the specs to it from the Specs table based on the matching specsId.

What is the proper way to do so?

Thanks,

Z

Comment: You should be using native Core Data relationships, not your own specsId properties.

Comment: [Core Data is not](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdTechnologyOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009296-SW1) a database manager. You should be constructing your model as an object graph, establishing relationships between entities. You should probably read up on what Core Data is and how to work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to do this is to drop the "specsId" field from the Device table and to create a relationship to the Specs table called something like "spec".

This way, once you have the Device object you can just use...

```
myDeviceObject.spec.<property of spec>;
```

to access the spec.

Without having the join you would have to create an `NSFetchRequest` to get the `Device` object that you want and then to create a new `NSFetchRequest` to get the `Spec` object for that `Device`.

The second NSFetchRequest will have a predicate something like...

```
@"specsId = %@", device.specsId
```

Comment: yeah, i ended up doing several fetch requests, i thought it could be done more elegantly, but that's the way it is. Thanks anyway!

Comment: LOL, it can be done more elegantly. You just need to set up you entity model properly. Nothing could by more elegant than myDeviceObject.spec to get the spec of a device. :-D